# Logstash mysql database data not loading to elasticsearch index

Tags: mysql, logstash, elastic-stack

I have been working on this all evening and it is driving me crazy. It is supposed to be very simple but it is not working. This works with Oracle but not with MySQL and I created similar db.config that is fed to logstash using -f option.

```
input {

 jdbc {
       jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/elk/logstash-5.6.0/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar"
       jdbc_driver_class => "Java::com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://serverName:3306/dbName?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true"
       jdbc_user => "userName"
       jdbc_password => "PasswordValue"

    statement => "select user_id, visitor_returning, config_os, visitor_days_since_last from visiting_table where user_id is not null"

    #optional extras I use 
      type => "visit"
      tags => ["awesome", "import"]
 }
```

}

output{
stdout {codec => json_lines}

```
if [type] == "visit"{   
        elasticsearch{
            hosts => "127.0.0.1"
            index => "visitDb"
            document_type => "visit_results"
        }
    }
stdout{}
```

}

Once I run the logstash, it is not loading the data into Elastic search index. I cannot even see the index named visitDb when I do the below.

curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'

```
health status index          uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
```

yellow open   .kibana        Fg6P7XuHSTaonbKEbLcz5A   1   1         21            3     56.5kb         56.5kb
yellow open   orderstotdb    obxZ38prTFCG0W-BFTIhgw   5   1         60            0    245.4kb        245.4kb
y

I am unable to figure out what is going on with MySQL. I can see the console log retrieving the data in json format and writing to console, but the index does not reflect in ElasticSearch nor shows up in Kibana to create index pattern.

Can someone please help ??

Comment: A couple of things to add. ElasticSearch indices load when data is obtained from OracleDB. I was initially thinking it is an issue with data types and removed apl the columns and reduced to 3 which are all varchar fields. Appreciate any help or pointers

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case any one else is having the same issue. Elastic Search rejects index names with upper case, since I had name visitDb with D capital, it was rejecting index name creation, go figure :) Hours lost in debugging different options.